# Killing a For loop in Julia array comprehension

Tags: arrays, julia, list-comprehension, break

I have the following line of code in Julia:

```
X=[(i,i^2) for i in 1:100 if i^2%5==0]
```

Basically, it returns a list of tuples `(i,i^2)` from `i=1 to 100` if the remainder of `i^2` and `5` is zero. What I want to do is, in the array comprehension, break out of the for loop if `i^2` becomes larger than `1000`. However, if I implement

```
X=[(i,i^2) for i in 1:100 if i^2%5==0 else break end]
```

I get the error: `syntax: expected "]"`.

Is there any way to easily break out of this for loop inside the array? I've tried looking online, but nothing came up.

Comment: I would really love if Julia would allow something like X=[(i,i^2) for i in 1:100 if i^2%5==0 until i^2 > 1000]; it would making functional programming in Julia easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. You could always just

```
tmp(i) = (j = i^2; j > 1000 ? false : j%5==0)
X=[(i,i^2) for i in 1:100 if tmp(i)]
```

Comment: In a later question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101965/array-comprehension-with-a-random-output-in-julia (edit: and  a more recent answer here) there was the comment that it was better to just write out the loop. I agree with this - this is just an attempt to answer the question as posed.

Answer (score 6):

It's a "fake" for-loop, so you can't `break` it. Take a look at the lowered code below:

```
julia> foo() = [(i,i^2) for i in 1:100 if i^2%5==0]
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_lowered foo()
LambdaInfo template for foo() at REPL[0]:1
:(begin 
        nothing
        #1 = $(Expr(:new, :(Main.##1#3)))
        SSAValue(0) = #1
        #2 = $(Expr(:new, :(Main.##2#4)))
        SSAValue(1) = #2
        SSAValue(2) = (Main.colon)(1,100)
        SSAValue(3) = (Base.Filter)(SSAValue(1),SSAValue(2))
        SSAValue(4) = (Base.Generator)(SSAValue(0),SSAValue(3))
        return (Base.collect)(SSAValue(4))
    end)
```

The output shows that `array comprehension` is implemented via [`Base.Generator`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/7d5a624dfe83ef67a706872b4666cb97e1c7f02f/base/generator.jl#L31-L38) which takes an iterator as input. It only supports the `[if cond(x)::Bool]` "guard" for now, so there is no way to use `break` here.

For your specific case, a workaround is to use [`isqrt`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/math.html#Base.isqrt):

```
julia> X=[(i,i^2) for i in 1:isqrt(1000) if i^2%5==0]
6-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (5,25)  
 (10,100)
 (15,225)
 (20,400)
 (25,625)
 (30,900)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a `for` loop is considered idiomatic in Julia and could be more readable in this instance. Also, it could be faster.

Specifically:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> tmp(i) = (j = i^2; j > 1000 ? false : j%5==0)
julia> X1 = [(i,i^2) for i in 1:100 if tmp(i)];

julia> @btime [(i,i^2) for i in 1:100 if tmp(i)];
  471.883 ns (7 allocations: 528 bytes)

julia> X2 = [(i,i^2) for i in 1:isqrt(1000) if i^2%5==0];

julia> @btime [(i,i^2) for i in 1:isqrt(1000) if i^2%5==0];
  281.435 ns (7 allocations: 528 bytes)

julia> function goodsquares()
           res = Vector{Tuple{Int,Int}}()
           for i=1:100
               if i^2%5==0 && i^2<=1000
                   push!(res,(i,i^2))
               elseif i^2>1000
                   break
               end
           end
           return res
       end
julia> X3 = goodsquares();

julia> @btime goodsquares();
  129.123 ns (3 allocations: 304 bytes)
```

So, another 2x improvement is nothing to disregard and the long function gives plenty of room for illuminating comments.

Comment: Aside from the early termination, there shouldn't be anything inherently faster about writing out a loop – that's what the comprehension code boils down to. It would be possible to allow a break or continue in a comprehension, but the semantics are a little unclear. Do any other languages (e.g. Python) allow it?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski The `isqrt` version terminates just as fast as the loop version and is still 2x slower. Why is that? (guess: taking a root is slow)

Comment: Re: last comment, the `isqrt` is not the culprit. Hand-coding the upper bound and running on more entries (up to 10,000) still has a 2x factor in favor of `goodsquares`