# Array Comprehension with a random output in Julia

Tags: arrays, random, julia, list-comprehension

[This question is an extension if one I asked earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097910/killing-a-for-loop-in-julia-array-comprehension). Basically, I am trying to write an array comprehension in Julia that calls a function `f(x)` whose output is a random number. When a random number less than 0.5 is reached, I want it to kill the function. I was able to write the following code:

> X=[f(i) for i in 1:1:100 if (j=f(i) ;j < 0.5 ? false: j>0.5)]

The problem with this is that this calls two separate instances of `f(x)`, and because `f(x)` is random every time, the above won't kill the for loop at the correct instance. I tried

> X=[J=f(i) for i in 1:1:100 if (J < 0.5 ? false: J>0.5)]

As an attempt to save that particular random number, but then it tells me J is not defined. Is there any way to save this particular random number to perform my array comprehension?

Comment: Why not just write a loop? This is a very simple loop.

Comment: This is really an abuse of array comprehensions. Write a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insisting on a one-line solution and inspired by @TasosPapastylianou, a fast solution would be :

```
X = ( r=Vector{Float64}() ; 
  any(i->(v=f(i) ; v>0.5 ? ( push!(r,v) ; false) : true), 1:100) 
  ; r )
```

*[ the one-line is split to three because it is a little long ;) ]*

Since, `f` is missing, to test this copy-paste this version with `rand`:

```
(r=ones(0); any(i->(v=rand(); v>0.5 ? (push!(r,v); false) : true), 1:10); r)
```

It benchmarks about 10% slower than Fengyang's function. The clever bit is leveraging `any`'s short-circuit implementation.

**ADDENDUM**: To generalize here is a version of Fengyang's `takewhile` to abstract the answer to this question:

```
collectwhilecond(f,cond,itr) = begin
    r=Vector{typeof(f(first(itr)))}()
    all(x->(y=f(x); cond(y) ? (push!(r,y);true):false),itr)
    return r
end
```

Now, we can implement the answer above as (with `joker` as `f`):

```
julia> joker(i) = 1.0 + 4*rand() - log(i)

julia> collectwhilecond(joker, x->x>=0.5, 1:100)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 4.14222
 3.42955
 2.76387
```

`collectwhilecond` is also type stable if Julia infers `f`'s return type.

**EDIT:** Using @tim's suggested method of inferring return type of `f` without pulling an element of `itr` and without risking an unstable `f` generating an error, the new `collectwhilecond` is:

```
collectwhilecond(f,cond,itr) = begin
    t = Base.promote_op(f,eltype(itr))  # unofficial and subject to change
    r = Vector{t}()
    all( x -> ( y=f(x) ; cond(y) ? (push!(r,y) ; true) : false), itr )
    return r
end
```

Comment: With `r = Vector{typeof(f(first(itr)))}()`, `push!(r,y)` can fail if `f` is not type stable.

Comment: @tim True. Is there anyway to know if `f` is type-stable? Or get its inferred return type?

Comment: `Base.promote_op` seems to work, but I don't know if its use is recommended. See my comment under Fengyang Wang's answer.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is essentially a simple `filter` operation:

```
filter(x -> x >= 0.5, [f(i) for i in 1:10])
```

This is basically what we used to rely on in the first place before the `if` part was implemented in list comprehensions in julia before v0.5

---

**EDIT:** As Dan pointed out, you may be after keeping all elements until the first element that is <0.5 instead, e.g.:

```
L = [f(i) for i in 1:10]; L[1 : findfirst(L.<0.5) - 1]
```

However, in this case, as others have pointed out, you might as well go for a normal for loop. A list comprehension will always process the whole list first, so it will not be faster. You *could* use a generator, but then you'd have to create your own special mechanism to make it stop at the right state (as Fengyang has suggested with `takewhile`).

So to answer the question in the comment, the fastest thing you could do in this case is a normal for loop that breaks appropriately. Furthermore, it is best wrapped in a function rather than evaluated globally, and it will speed up even further if you specify the type of your variables.

Comment: Not exactly, it's a modified filter, since it stops adding elements after the first element dropped

Comment: Would filter be faster than a regular loop? I'm trying to write the code so it runs as fast as possible, and I'm dealing with very big arrays (on the order of a few million elements).

Comment: @DanGetz ah, thanks. That detail isn't at all obvious without the linked question. (assuming the linked question premise still applies).

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do this with what's usually called `takewhile` on a generator

```
X = collect(takewhile(x -> x ≥ 0.5, Generator(f, 1:100)))
```

which requires an implementation of `takewhile`, such as the one in [this blog post](http://slendermeans.org/julia-iterators.html), or your own (it's not too hard to do). `takewhile` has a reasonably easy name to read and is as concise as you might like.

However I think often it's both more readable and more convenient to *write a loop*:

```
X = Float64[]
for i = 1:100
    j = f(i)
    if j < 0.5
        break
    else
        push!(X, j)
    end
end
```

Comment: How do you determine the element type of the array? Should one use `Base.promote_op(f, Int)`?

Comment: Would using takewhile on a generator be faster than using a loop? I'm dealing with arrays with upwards of a million elements, and I want the code to go as fast as possible.

Comment: No, of course the for loop will always be fastest, though a good implementation of `takewhile` might have low overhead.

Comment: @tim A better way is `Base._return_type(f, Tuple{Int})`, but this requires v0.6.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, using a loop is the right way to go. But if trying 'other' solutions, the following is short and confusing and educational about Channels which are seldom mentioned in Stack Overflow:

```
collect(Channel(c->begin
        i=1
        while true 
            v = rand()
            if v<0.5 || i>100 return else put!(c,v) end
            i+=1 
        end 
    end, ctype=Float64))
```

Replace `rand()` with `f(i)` as appropriate.
And BTW don't use this solution because it is 1000x slower than a simple loop. Perhaps of value if Channel is a RemoteChannel and `f(i)` is some big stochastic simulation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to squeeze the maximum possible performance, I'd say there are two options depending on which is the bottleneck.

1. `f` is very fast, but allocations are an issue. The following code computes `f` twice but saves on the allocation part (as `push!` will sometimes reallocate memory, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751225/how-efficient-are-push-and-append-methods-in-julia) ):

`i = findfirst(t -> f(t) > 0.5, 1:100)
w = f.(1:(i-1))`

2. `f` is very slow and computing it twice is too expensive. Then just do a loop with `push!` as already recommended. You may want to look at `sizehint!` to further improve performance.

In general, you don't need to ask what is slower and what is faster: ypu can simply benchmark your particular use case with the excellent [BenchmarkTools](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) package.

Comment: If `f` is random (as suggested) it could be problematic to recalculate

Comment: I don't think _any_ not completely trivial function that runs `n` times will be faster than memory allocation. If you're worried about memory allocation, doing a `sizehint!` before the `push!`s is better.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but then I benchmarked and for simple enough `f` (I used squaring a float), the first solution was twice as fast (even when the second used `sizehint!`). It's probably not just the allocation (I found some discussion here  comparing `push!` with filling a preallocated array in case you are curious: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5364 ). Still, I agree that `push!` seems by far the most natural approach (especially if `f` is random of course...)